# Enabling line wrap with React-Syntax-Highlighter?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [React Syntax Highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter) to highlight code when I render a markdown file to HTML.

I see that I have to set `wrapLines`  to `true` so that there's a `span` parent for each line. However, I'm confused on what I should be passing to `lineProps` to enable line wrap?

For an example, you can look at this screenshot.

[image]

I'd like to preserve the line numbers too.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 19):

**Update**: as of react-syntax-highlighter `14.0.0`, you can use the prop `wrapLongLines` in order to wrap the lines to the next line. [See details here](https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter/pull/309).

For versions before 14:
Here's what worked for me – wrapping each line it's own  with `wrapLines` prop and then adding a custom style to each line with `lineProps`. Hat tip to a Nitesh's previous answer. Note that `showLineNumbers` won't work correctly with text-wrapping in this way.

```js
<SyntaxHighlighter
  lineProps={{style: {wordBreak: 'break-all', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}}
  wrapLines={true} 
  language="jsx" 
  style={a11yDark}
>
```

Comment: Worked for me!

Just a comment: for boolean props, you don't need to set `={true}`, just passing it is enough:

`
<SyntaxHighlighter
  lineProps={{style: {wordBreak: 'break-all', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}}
  wrapLines 
  language="jsx" 
  style={a11yDark}
/>
`

Comment: My NPM downloaded `13.5.3` version for an unknow reason, that made me so confused.

Comment: im on version 15, but the solution for <v14 worked best for me. The `wrapLongLines` prop broke the long lines of text in a really weird way by removing spaces and stacking the text on top of eachother

Answer (score 2):

This was also really confusing to me.

The `wrapLines` is **NOT** about wrapping lines of code at a pre-defined length or the container width.

It's about surrounding each line in a containing DOM element ("wrapping" the line in a DOM element).

I suppose the name of the option should probably be changed.

#### Sources

- Original issue: https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter/issues/44
- Pull Request: https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

As per https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter docs you can use :

`lineProps` - props to be passed to the span wrapping each line if wrapLines is true. Can be either an object or a function that receives current line number as argument and returns props object.

try this :

```
<SyntaxHighlighter
  lineProps={{style: {paddingBottom: 8}}}
  wrapLines={true}
  showLineNumbers={true}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

sandbox snippet :
https://codesandbox.io/s/syntax-highlighter-demo-skhkw