# NPM not installing latest version of package

Tags: npm, npm-install

Steps to reproduce:

```sh
npm init
npm i react-syntax-highlighter
```

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.3"
  }
}
```

I have the latest version, hourra !

---

```sh
npm init
npm i @storybook/components
npm i react-syntax-highlighter
```

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/components": "^6.2.9",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^13.5.3"
  }
}
```

Wtf ? It took me 2h and a lot of [luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492403/enabling-line-wrap-with-react-syntax-highlighter) to find out I had not the latest package of `react-syntax-highlighter`, and it seem it is because `@storybook/components` use `react-syntax-highlighter@13.5.3`.

I find it completely non-intuitive that `npm i <package_name>` would not always install latest. Why is NPM designed that way ? And how can I configure NPM to always download the latest when I do `npm i <package_name>`. Basically making `@latest` the default behavior (I thought it was default).

Answer (score 0):

Because the author of [storybookjs/storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs) version 6.2.9 of his package to specific version of a dependent package.

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/e74c0b7514b58c1308400958275e1623ea973f0d/lib/components/package.json#L58