# Wrap & Fix Position of text in HTML code block in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Synopsis**: In ReactJS, I have a string of HTML code that I've formatted using [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) and styled using [react-syntax-highlighter](https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter):

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { a11yDark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs";
let beautify = require("js-beautify").html;

export default function App() {
  const beautifyHTML = () => {
    const code =
      "<div><h1>Small Piece of Text.</h1><div><h2>AReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongPieceOfText.</h2></div><h3>AnotherReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongPieceOfText.</h3></div>";
    const beautifiedHTML = beautify(code, {
      indent_size: 2,
      brace_style: "expand"
    });
    return beautifiedHTML;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SyntaxHighlighter language="html" style={a11yDark}>
        {beautifyHTML()}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the UI, this is what I get:
[image]

Here's the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-wilson-19j4uj?file=/src/styles.css) to see it all in action and **for you to edit**.

**Problem**: What I would like to have happen is two things:

1. Wrap the line at the width of the div, so that the horizontal scroll does not show up.
2. When the line wraps to the next line, the overflowing text should not start at the beginning of the line, but right below where the original line started.

To try wrapping the text (Problem 1), I tried adding the following  as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag), but it seems to only work when the code is wrapped in a `pre` tag, which I do not have here...

```
.App code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: [There's a CSS value for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text#breaking_long_words). I'm not sure about question 2.

Comment: Yup, I edited my post to say that I tried that and it did not work...

Comment: The wrapping part is easy, starting indented on the new line gives me a headache xD

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I used VSCode as my IDE and Code Sandbox to demo. Both have the same results when I try to wrap the text using that last bit of code in my post.

Comment: [This is my hack](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-haslett-ynozee) so far... only works for one set indentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492403/enabling-line-wrap-with-react-syntax-highlighter might also help

Comment: Also, do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284453/react-native-text-going-off-my-screen-refusing-to-wrap-what-to-do, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Thanks for these links. I'm not able to figure out how to do problem 2 still.

Comment: @Zach Jensz  Thanks for these links. I'm not able to figure out how to do problem 2 still.